# Formula for helper column(s) that determines singular or combined values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am creating helper columns to assist me in reviewing our data, but I am running across an issue with one. What I am trying to accomplish is to create a helper column that tells me, by month, what type of medications a person is prescribed, and then combines multiple selections for the same name into a new name.

A sample data set would be:

```
A          B             C
1/1/2016   Doe, John     Oral
1/1/2016   Doe, John     Compound
1/1/2016   Doe, John     Oral
2/1/2016   Smith, Jane   Oral
2/1/2016   Smith, Jane   Oral
2/1/2016   Adams, Tom    Compound
2/1/2016   Doe, John     Oral
```

So, for example, if John Doe was prescribed 2 oral medications and 1 compounded medication on 1/1/2016, the helper column would sort out that the three medications belong to the same person and are of two different types, so changes them to Combined. It would end up something akin to "1-Doe, John-Combined", displayed here:

```
D
1-Doe, John-Combined
1-Doe, John-Combined
1-Doe, John-Combined
2-Smith, Jane-Oral
2-Smith, Jane-Oral
2-Adams, Tom-Compound
2-Doe, John-Oral
```

So far, all I have is the concatenation by month:

```
=MONTH(A2)&"-"&B2&"-"
```

But I am not certain how to tackle the portion of the formula that will present the type of medication and combine (if required). Also, if necessary, more than one column can be created.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use SUMPRODUCT to test:

```
=MONTH(A1) & "-" & B1& "-" & IF(SUMPRODUCT((MONTH($A$1:$A$7)=MONTH(A1))*($B$1:$B$7=B1)*($C$1:$C$7<>C1))>0,"Combined",C1)
```

[image]